# Who should nominate him self as a candidate in elections?

Tags: discussion, election, votes

I just saw that there is an election on our community & as we can see that many peoples are nominating their self as an aspirants in the election for the post of moderator.

I also filled the nomination but then withdrew my name from the nominators list just because I felt that I still need to know much more about magento before standing as an aspirant in the election for the magento community.

My question is that who should stand as an aspirant for the post of moderator & On what basis we should judge them that whether he is really a good candidate or not for the post of magento moderator?

Comment: This is a really good question. I hope all the candidates see it.

Comment: Thank you @Marius ! I would be great full to have your answer on this

Comment: I'm thinking, I'm thinking. But I guess there is no perfect answer on this. All I can do is give you my opinion. I will try to write something today.

Answer (score 14):

Since (almost) everyone can sign up for the election and my vote counts just as much as the next person's, what follows is just my opinion and should not be taken as fact in any way. It does not mean I'm right, it does not mean I'm wrong either.

**You should nominate yourself if:**

- you have proven yourself as an active member in the past. A good indicator of this may be the number of "**Moderation Badges**" you have (https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges). Another indicator may be the number of days you visited the website that you can find in your profile page. Or the number of posts you had on meta.
- You think something is wrong with the website and you have a plan to fix it. (you should do this anyway even if you don't want to be a moderator).
- You value education instead of destruction for new comers.

**You should not nominate yourself if:**

- You just want to brag to your friends that you have a diamond next to your name in a stackexchange website.
- You did not really participate in this website much, but being a moderator will motivate you to do so. The motivation to participate should not be influenced by being a moderator or not.
- you have close to none reviews in the review queue in all the categories.
- You have no idea what the meta website is.
- A significant part of your posts (questions and answers, but mostly questions) have low score and a lot of comments that require improvement.
- You ask questions like this: [Regrading 2018 Community Moderator Election](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2300/146) for which you could have found the answer easily.

**When should you withdraw from the election:**

- When you see that your candidate score in the election has 1 digit followed by `/40`.

Comment: I totally agree with your opinions & the last-one is really **mark-able** I hope those who are standing as an aspirants with 1/40 or below 10/40 should have a look into this.

Answer (score 7):

This question is interesting, but difficult to give a full qualifying answer. Any way I will put my two cents here.

**You can be a candidate if:**

1. You are around here at least for one year and during that period you were constantly put effort to improve this community. Why one year? Each community works different. It will take some time to understand the community, how the community works here, what are the things we can do/no-do etc. So a buffer time of one year would take to understand the community in my opinion.
2. You are constantly moderating in community. There are lot of things come here. You are constantly monitoring the community activities and report any issues to moderators for immediate actions, taking actions against on false contents which you have privilege to do. Upvote questions and answers which are really relevant.
3. You are taking a humble approach to newbies. We are stable now. So we don't need to do a strict scrutiny to the new questions which are coming to our site now. We can take a humble approach now and teach a newbie how to ask a question and how to answer a question. This will enrich and inspire them and that will eventually leads to more frequent participation from their side. This is a must requirement in my opinion.
4. You have a quiet good knowledge about the moderation and your additional responsibilities if you become a moderator. For this, you should engage with the moderators and take feedback from them. Meta is a wonderful place to ask such questions if you are not clear with the approach you should take in a given situation or you need assistance from the moderators.
5. Last but not least, you are a person who are using all your moderation privileges in its fullest. This is a MUST.

**You should not nominate if:**

1. You just answered 5 questions and now you feel you know everything about moderation. We appreciate your effort, but which is not enough for moderation.
2. You don't have patience and you are responding to any no-do action with    your first instinct or rage. Remember patience is the quality a moderator need. A best moderator will engage the community to take a decision if it is possible even if he can do that action with a simple click.
3. You don't know what are the rules in this community
4. You are not using your moderator privileges in it's fullest. Oh boy!! this is critical one.

**Why I am not applying this time**

If you look my profile, I am eligible to apply for election. But I am not considering me as an eligible candidate, since:

1. My moderation in this community for the past 5 month is very less. At least, it is not satisfying myself. I am not getting 2 hours to spend here due to my busy office work.
2. I know people who are constantly engaging with the community do exists and I would love to vote for them. Within two days, the people in my mind are not applying, then I will shoot a notification to them. This is something that I do always whenever an election happens.
3. Most importantly, I fear I could not find much time to do my moderation duties in the coming future. I think this is the reason why one of our existing moderator back out from his position. I really do appreciate that.

Now please keep this in mind and think. If you still feel you are good, then nominate yourself. :)

Comment: I already mentioned here that I withdrew my name from the nomination as because I am not considering myself as a good candidate for the post of **Moderator**. I just asked this here to be clear that who should apply & to whom should we vote for this post, Thank you for your response!

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI My answer is not intended to you. This answer is my opinion to your question. Since this question is in general in the context, the answer also treat like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see in nomination page there are block showing of **candidate score**. You can judge by that which candidate is suitable for job. That is the way i choose whom to vote.

**candidate score 37/40**

```
reputation >= 20k
moderation badges: 5/8
editing badges: 6/6
participation badges: 6/6
```

*Note: It is my opinion to choose candidate*

Answer (score 0):

I agree what Qaisar said ,

Apart from this you can click on review  and meta post link to see their meta participation, how they have answered some question and take part in discussions.

By clicking on reviews you can see their participation in close vote/Low Quality post review/ suggested Edits etc..

from review link you can easily identify how frequent they participate in moderator activity to make site more clean

**candidate score 23/40**

```
reputation 9k
moderation badges: 5/8
editing badges: 4/6
participation badges: 5/6
```