# Regrading 2018 Community Moderator Election

Tags: support, election, moderators

How will others vote for moderators who stands for election recently ?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1

Every election has three phases:

Nomination

Primary

Election

once Nomination completed , than you can see an **option** to **vote**....

[image]