# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Magento's [second moderator election](https://magento.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Sander Mangel] [image: Amit Bera]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking [philwinkle](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/336/philwinkle) who is stepping down from the moderator role.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6483805292462080/0).

Comment: Congrat Sander and amit :)

Comment: Congrats for both of you , we expect more & more `answers` from you guys :)

Comment: you done great job  philwinkle  , we will surely miss you.....

Comment: Congrats Amit and Sander

Comment: Congrats @AmitBera and sander Much deserved :)

Comment: congrats Sander and amit..

Comment: Congrats guys ! Well deserved

Comment: Congratulations Amit and Sander

Comment: Congratulations to both for their result. I'd like to point out that Mr Bera (whilst not having English as a first language, as is with many MSE users) has consistently displayed very poor grammar and post formatting choices over his (long and incredibly valuable) contributing time here. I hope that as a moderator stewarding the MSE community that he can lift his game to try and keep a high quality of content on this site.

Comment: Congrats @AmitBera

Comment: @RobbieAverill, thanks  for your suggestion. I will try to improvement my quality on English language  .

Comment: @AmitBera congratulation sir

Answer (score 13):

`-1` ... 16% voted and i guess 90% of them did not read [Who should nominate him self as a candidate in elections?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2295/who-should-nominate-him-self-as-a-candidate-in-elections)

Comment: Yes, the results are more along the lines of "who has more points" than "who is involved in moderation". Better luck next time.

Comment: best of luck @sv3n for next time.